# Squeryl - HikariCP - mySql - Distributing Read Traffic to Slaves

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, master-slave, squeryl, hikaricp

I'm trying to follow the steps listed at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html which states

> To enable this functionality, use the com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
>   class when configuring your application server's connection pool

From https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP - it says

> HikariCP will attempt to resolve a driver through the DriverManager
>   based solely on the jdbcUrl

So is this configuration all thats needed?

> db.default.url=jdbc:mysql:replication ...

Squeryl has has a number of db Adapters; but my understanding is these are unrelated?
http://squeryl.org/api/index.html#org.squeryl.adapters.MySQLInnoDBAdapter

Sorry for the key word loading - I'm just not too sure where I need to focus

Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I find myself back here - please note, hikari doesn't support the Replication driver.

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/625#issuecomment-251613688

`MySQL Replication Driver simply does NOT work together with HikariCP.`

And

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hikari-cp/KtKgzR8COrE/higEHoPkAwAJ

`... nobody running anything resembling a mission critical application takes MySQL's driver-level replication support seriously.`

Answer (score 1):

For people hitting this in 2020, Hikari uses

```
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
```

as a data source. If I look at the code of the above class. It has a method named **connect** which returns **Connection** instance.

```
protected Connection getConnection(Properties props) throws SQLException {
    String jdbcUrlToUse = null;
    if (!this.explicitUrl) {
        StringBuffer jdbcUrl = new StringBuffer("jdbc:mysql://");
        if (this.hostName != null) {
            jdbcUrl.append(this.hostName);
        }

        jdbcUrl.append(":");
        jdbcUrl.append(this.port);
        jdbcUrl.append("/");
        if (this.databaseName != null) {
            jdbcUrl.append(this.databaseName);
        }

        jdbcUrlToUse = jdbcUrl.toString();
    } else {
        jdbcUrlToUse = this.url;
    }

    Properties urlProps = mysqlDriver.parseURL(jdbcUrlToUse, (Properties)null);
    urlProps.remove("DBNAME");
    urlProps.remove("HOST");
    urlProps.remove("PORT");
    Iterator keys = urlProps.keySet().iterator();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        props.setProperty(key, urlProps.getProperty(key));
    }

    return mysqlDriver.connect(jdbcUrlToUse, props);
}
```

where **mysqlDriver** is an instance of

```
protected static final NonRegisteringDriver mysqlDriver;
```

if i check the connect method of NonRegisteringDriver class. It looks like this

```
public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
    if (url != null) {
        if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url, "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://")) {
            return this.connectLoadBalanced(url, info);
        }

        if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url, "jdbc:mysql:replication://")) {
            return this.connectReplicationConnection(url, info);
        }
    }

    Properties props = null;
    if ((props = this.parseURL(url, info)) == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!"1".equals(props.getProperty("NUM_HOSTS"))) {
        return this.connectFailover(url, info);
    } else {
        try {
            com.mysql.jdbc.Connection newConn = ConnectionImpl.getInstance(this.host(props), this.port(props), props, this.database(props), url);
            return newConn;
        } catch (SQLException var6) {
            throw var6;
        } catch (Exception var7) {
            SQLException sqlEx = SQLError.createSQLException(Messages.getString("NonRegisteringDriver.17") + var7.toString() + Messages.getString("NonRegisteringDriver.18"), "08001", (ExceptionInterceptor)null);
            sqlEx.initCause(var7);
            throw sqlEx;
        }
    }
}
```

After looking at the code, it looks like it supports. I haven't tried it till now. Will try and let you know from personal experience. From code, it looks directly feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Squeryl offers different MySQL adapters because innodb supports referential keys, while myisam does not.  It seems like what your'e doing should be handled at the connection pool level, so I don't think your Squeryl configuration will have an affect.

I've never configured Hikari for replicated MySQL, but if it requires an alternative JDBC driver I'd be surprised if you can provide a JDBC URL and everything just works.  I'm guessing that Hikari's default functionality is to pick the plain vanilla MySQL JDBC driver unless you tell it otherwise.  Luckily, Hikari has quite a few [config options](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#essentials) including the ability to set a specific `driverClassName`.

Comment: HikariCP 2.3.6 has just been published, and contains a bugfix to look for a specific driver when ``driverClassName`` is specified.  Previous behavior was to always use URL-based resolution.  Still, looking the MySQL code, it seems that MySQL should still be registering the ReplicationDriver automatically (and URL-based resolution should work).

Answer (score 0):

Replication allows for a different URL:

`jdbc:mysql:replication://[server1],[server2],[server2]/[database]`

I've never tried it, but I assume this will resolve to the ReplicationDriver.